# Unset Session Variables on Meteor.js Hot Code Reload

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

How do you unset a Session variable when a hot code reload occurs?

I have the following subscription code and wants to perform `Session.set('score', '')` on a hot code reload.

```
Deps.autorun( function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('score', Meteor.userId(), function() {
        Session.set('score', new Date().getTime())
    })
})
```

Comment: Why don't you just simply perform the reset in Meteor.startup ? It works for me.

Comment: Or, you can use the `reload` package and hook an event handler with `Reload._onMigrate`.

Answer (score 2):

Session.keys is an object so you can delete the 'score' like this on startup.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    delete Session.keys['score'];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Reload._onMigrate private API to have finer control of what happen during hot code reload.  There is a screencast on this topic.

https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/meteor-core-systems/using-a-custom-onmigrate-api

Comment: That link is dead. This is what you want: https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-using-a-custom-onmigrate-api